# PHP5.2: installing support for .phar files on Windows

Tags: php, windows, phar

I am trying to install support for php's archive file format into windows servers that have php5.2.  I tried to do this using `pecl install phar`.  But I am getting this error:

```
The DSP phar.dsp does not exist
```

Can anybody help me figure this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pecl install` on windows, you need to have Microsoft Visual Studio installed.

It's probably easier to use the `phar.dll` shipped with your PHP setup program.